# C# Put multiple methods and call them into the main method

Tags: c#, if-statement, methods

Sample code below is just a short one, my real code for  one if statement is more than 1000 lines of code and those need  to be called multiple times. So,  to save lines I plan on putting it into a method and just calling that method, which is only around 1 line?

I was wondering if there is a possible way of putting multiple if else statements into MULTIPLE methods, and then calling those methods in the main method. If Method **SuperSignalQ1** is true, then it will check method **SuperSignalQ2**, and so on.

I need this because without the method, my current code is more than 900k, which crashes my PC. This is the only way I could think of shortening my code, by putting it into a method and calling it in the main method as needed, rather than typing those 100s of lines everytime I need those.

So basically my question is:

1. How to call a method in the main method
2. How to check if that method is true so that it can then proceed to the next method. I receive error when doing the code in the **MainCalculation**

***Cannot convert method group 'SuperSignalQ1' to non-delegate type 'bool'. Did you intend to invoke the method?***

```
public void SuperSignalQ1()
{
    if(RSI > RSI2) 
    {
        if(CCI > CCI2) //There are actually more than 20 if else here which is around 1000 lines
        {
            return;
        }
    }
    
}
public void SuperSignalQ2()
{
    if(RSI2 > RSI3)
    {
        if(CCI2 > CCI3) //There are actually more than 20 if else here which is around 1000 lines
        {
            return;
        }
    }
}
public void SuperSignalQ3()
{
    if(RSI3 > RSI4)
    {
        if(CCI3 > CCI4) //There are actually more than 20 if else here which is around 1000 lines
        {
            return;
        }
    }
}
public void MainCalculation()
{
    if (SuperSignalQ1 = True)
    {
        if(SuperSignalQ2 = True)
        {
            if SuperSignalQ3 = True)
            {
                SetColor(Color.White);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So basically, put multiple nested if statement into multiple methods, and then do an boolean check of those methods in the main method

Comment: In regards to your error, you need to declare the method return type as bool instead of void.
But I suggest restructuring your code, and use multiple classes for different functions instread of cramming everything into a single file with if-else

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have

`public void SuperSignalQ1()`

and later on you have

`if (SuperSignalQ1 = True)`

This if statement is broken.

In c#, you test with the double equals:

`if (someVariable == true)`

What you've got is an assignment statement, because there's one equals sign.

You're also missing some brackets, so C# thinks you are referring to it as a variable instead of a method.

So it thinks you are trying to assign a value of `True` to the method pointer.  Which it quite rightly complains about.

It *looks* like you actually want those methods to return a boolean value, and you could do something like this:

```
public bool SuperSignalQ1()
{
    if(RSI > RSI2) 
    {
        if(CCI > CCI2) //There are actually more than 20 if else here which is around 1000 lines
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;   // if none of the conditions are valid
}
public bool SuperSignalQ2()
{
    if(RSI2 > RSI3)
    {
        if(CCI2 > CCI3) //There are actually more than 20 if else here which is around 1000 lines
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;   // if none of the conditions are valid

}
public bool SuperSignalQ3()
{
    if(RSI3 > RSI4)
    {
        if(CCI3 > CCI4) //There are actually more than 20 if else here which is around 1000 lines
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
public void MainCalculation()
{
    if (SuperSignalQ1() == true)
    {
        if(SuperSignalQ2() == true)
        {
            if (SuperSignalQ3() == true)
            {
                SetColor(Color.White);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**BUT**

- For boolean, you don't usually use the `==` format, you'd just go `if (SuperSignalQ1())`
- As @aether643 suggested, you might want to refactor your code so you don't have such a long chunk of code without mental breaks
- In C#, you **can** actually do assignments in `if` tests.  Don't do that.